# Merge Contour Boundary for Polygons QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, dem, elevation, contour

Hoping this is fairly simple but haven't been able to find much online. I am trying to create some elevation polygons from a DEM model.

Right now I am getting this after getting the contours, converting to multipart, then polygons. But you can see its messing up some of the unbounded contours

[image]

Is there any way I can merge a boundary box and then get the polygons to show up correctly? Based on elevation

[image]

Comment: I'm not seeing the contour polygons option in the toolbox, just the contour option. Has it moved I'm  using version 3.10.13

Comment: Hmm. I have 3.1.4 but definitely dont see another option below contour. Maybe I will try reinstalling. I just upgraded to QGIS 3.10.13 so maybe something weird is going on

Comment: That worked! Is there a way to only display the polygons and not the contour lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can directly use the GDAL contour polygons tool. It is available from GDAL version 2.4.0. To see which GDAL version your QGIS installation uses go to `Menu Help / About`, see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kc3Ld.png). If installed, it looks like this:

[image]

If you have GDAL >= 2.4.0, but the entry `contour polygons` does not appear in the QGIS processing toolbox, you can use the "normal" contour tool and simply add the parameter `-p` (as described in the [documentation](http://gdal.org/programs/gdal_contour.html#cmdoption-gdal_contour-p)), see: [image]

Be aware, it can take some time. I used a DEM that took 27 minutes (50.7 KB GeoTiff, 3600*3600 pixels, Float32).

To get rid of the contours, simply change the `stroke style` to no `No Pen`, see:

[image]

Click to `symbol` bar to reach the settings above: [image]

Comment: Thank you so much, fantastic !!!

Comment: A Christmas present... ;-)

Comment: Once the solution is here, you might also want to delete the comments for reaching this solution