# Create vector out of a DEM in QGIS

Tags: qgis, dem

I would like to create a vector from my DEM raster so that it looks like the example I attached as an image. I want the altitude levels of the Alps in Austria to be represented in 5 different color gradations. I tried to make a vector out of the raster using "Contour" tools, but I don't want to create contour lines. Does anyone have an idea how to do it?

[image: Example]

Comment: You can also [reclassify](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html#qgisreclassifybytable) the DEM and style the output to achieve the same appearance

Comment: @BERA Or you can can simply just style the raster with discrete intervals, no need of reclassification or vectorizing (polygon contours) at all. I personally would go with hillshade style anyway instead of this style, or combination of it.

Comment: @Miro actually your solution produced the best result for me, thank you!

Comment: Glad it helps. One small tip if you go this way, Symbology for rasters have bottom section called Resampling which does help a lot with 'pixelation' effect of rasters when turned to cubic or so from Nearest neighbour, making raster look smoother.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of contour lines, create contour polygons: Menu <kbd>Processing</kbd> > <kbd>Toolbox</kbd> > <kbd>Contour Polygons</kbd>([see QGIS documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rasterextraction.html#contour-polygons)).

*It is a tool provided by GDAL library, needs GDAL 2.4.0 or higher (should be the case in newer QGIS versions), [see here for details](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/382907/88814). For older versions, GRASS tool [`r.recode`](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass82/manuals/r.recode.html) or even raster calculator would be an alternative, [see here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/397430/88814).*

*Created in a few minutes from a DEM with interval 800 m:*
[image]

Comment: See also this post, helped me today, as I would get an error message trying this algorythm:   https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/463507/contour-polygons-warning-model-file-not-specified