# Contour Polygons Warning: Model file not specified

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

When I am running the tool Contour Polygons, I got this warning:

```
GDAL command:
gdal_contour -p -amax ELEV_MAX -amin ELEV_MIN -b 1 -i 100.0 -f "Interlis 2" /home/<myname>/Documents/raster/file-srtm.tif /tmp/processing_fEvxEm/1f923f86609b47b3b4da3e977fcd7103/OUTPUT.xtf
GDAL command output:
Warning 1: Model file not specified.
Process returned error code 1
Execution completed in 0.62 seconds
Results:
{'OUTPUT': '/tmp/processing_fEvxEm/1f923f86609b47b3b4da3e977fcd7103/OUTPUT.xtf'}

Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.
• /tmp/processing_fEvxEm/1f923f86609b47b3b4da3e977fcd7103/OUTPUT.xtf
You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.
```

I am unsure of what to do next. The warning message I received did not provide any relevant information about the potential problem.

In addition, I downloaded the DEM from the USGS website and also used the SRTM downloader plugin. However, I received the same warning message both times. I am also using the native QGIS package.

Here is my system info:

```
QGIS version 3.32.0-Lima
QGIS code revision 311a8cb8a6
Qt version 5.15.3
Python version 3.10.6
GDAL/OGR version 3.4.1
PROJ version 8.2.1
EPSG Registry database version v10.041 (2021-12-03)
GEOS version 3.10.2-CAPI-1.16.0
SQLite version 3.37.2
PDAL version 2.3.0
PostgreSQL client version 14.8 (Ubuntu 14.8-0ubuntu0.22.04.1)
SpatiaLite version 5.0.1
QWT version 6.1.4
QScintilla2 version 2.11.6
OS version Linux Mint 21.1


Active Python plugins
SRTM-Downloader 3.1.17
nominatim 1.4.5
OSMDownloader 1.0.3
quick_map_services 0.19.33
Qgis2threejs 2.7.1
QuickOSM 2.2.2
processing 2.12.99
db_manager 0.1.20
MetaSearch 0.3.6
grassprovider 2.12.99
```

Comment: I can confirm that I am getting the same response. Should we file a bug report? I found your post when trying to find out what this means... This worked fine before I upgraded to QGIS version: 3.32.0-Lima. my issue: QGIS version: 3.32.0-Lima QGIS code revision: 311a8cb8a65 Qt version: 5.15.3 Python version: 3.9.5 GDAL version: 3.7.0 GEOS version: 3.11.2-CAPI-1.17.2 PROJ version: Rel. 9.2.1, June 1st, 2023 PDAL version: 2.5.3 (git-version: 7ec4e6) Algorithm started at: 2023-07-18T12:54:19 Algorithm 'Contour to Polygon' starting… Input parameters: { 'contourmax' : 1, 'contourmax (2)' : -1, 'date

Answer (score 3):

The issue seems to be with the use of the Interlis 2 driver.

If you run the same tool to output to a shapefile or Geopackage it should work.

try:

```
gdal_contour -p -amax ELEV_MAX -amin ELEV_MIN -b 1 -i 100.0 -f "GPKG" /home/<myname>/Documents/raster/file-srtm.tif /tmp/processing_fEvxEm/1f923f86609b47b3b4da3e977fcd7103/OUTPUT.gpkg
```

I had success changing the output file type.

If you want to change the default file type used for QGIS temporary layers you can find it under settings. Find details on this solution https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/54375.

[image: settings page]

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me.