# QGIS smooth mapzen DEM to create a very simplified topographic map

Tags: qgis, dem, topography

I am using Mapzen global terrain to create a topographic map.

How can I get a very simplified result like on the map of Greece?
Should I use contours lines ? And how to smooth them ? (wich algorithm to use ?).

What I have:

[image]

What I want :

[image]

What I tried :
**[image: strong text]**

Scale reduction in symbology (but i am still in raster mode)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Solution 1: Discrete layer Styling

Simply create the effect using layer style: set it to singleband pseudocolor, choose a white to black color ramp and manually classify depending on the elevation values you want to group together:

*See how to do it; additionally, I set a transparency value of 100% for values -9999 to 0 to render the sea transparent to make the OpenStreetMap background visible there:*
[image]

### Solution 2: Reclassify

1. Run [Reclassify by Table](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html#qgisreclassifybytable) and define the elevation values for which you want to groupt together to a single elevation class, e.g. like in the screenshot.
2. To "smooth", use Majority filter, see [this answer for details](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/396622/88814).

   *Result after step 1, based on Mapzen Global Terrain and the reclassification table you can see:*
   [image]

### Solution 3: Contour polygons

Alternatively, you can create contour polygons:

1. See [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/461221/88814) how to create contour polygons.
2. As an option, use [`smooth()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#smooth) with [Geoemtry Generator](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392619/88814) to get smoother forms.

   *Contour polygons after step 1 with interval 500 meters, deleted those below sea level, color with data driven override > assistant set to field `ELEV_MAX` (automatically created by the contour polygon algorithm) and values from 0 to 3500 with a withe to black color ramp:*
   [image]